# Loading raster layer from URL in QGIS Attribute table

Tags: qgis, raster, attribute-table, actions, addlayer

I have a map index polygon layer and want to load the raster from the URL filled-in attribute table using action.

My attribute table is below:

[image]

I had written in the action toolbar

```py
from qgis.utils import iface

rasterurl="[%alos_dem%]"
iface addRasterLayer(rasterurl,"[%sheetno%]")
```

[image: Code]

When I run this action by right-clicking it says that:

> 'No feature found at this position'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As action type choose **Python** instead of Open URL. Make sure to add the missing dot in your code between `iface` and `addRasterLayer` and to reference the correct field (in your screenshot it says `"Sheet_No"` but in your code its `"sheetno"`). Also check if you have the correct url, for me it says server not found when trying osm.com. About your error

> 'No feature found at this position'.

you need to make sure, that there actually is a feature where you click on the canvas.

```py
from qgis.utils import iface
rasterurl="[%alos_dem%]"
iface.addRasterLayer(rasterurl,"[%Sheet_No%]")
```

[image]

Comment: yes, it works. Thanks